# Python pandas transpose sumarizing content

Tags: python, pandas, count, transpose

I want to transform this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Filter 1': ['False','False','False','False'],
    'Filter 2': ['True','False','False','True'],
    'Filter 3': ['True','True','True','True']
})
print(df)

  Filter 1 Filter 2 Filter 3
----------------------------
0    False     True     True
1    False    False     True
2    False    False     True
3    False     True     True
```

Into this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'Filter': ['Filter 1', 'Filter 2', 'Filter 3'],
    'True': [0,2,4],
    'False': [4,2,0]
})
print(result)

     Filter  True  False
------------------------
0  Filter 1     0      4
1  Filter 2     2      2
2  Filter 3     4      0
```

Can you help me? It's a traspose + count values I can not fix, neither find

Kind regards!

Answer (score 4):

This is value count:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).T
```

Output:

```
          False  True
Filter 1    4.0   0.0
Filter 2    2.0   2.0
Filter 3    0.0   4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) + [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df2 = df.melt(var_name='Filter')
pd.crosstab(df2['Filter'], df2['value'], colnames=[None]).reset_index()
```

---

```
     Filter  False  True
0  Filter 1      4     0
1  Filter 2      2     2
2  Filter 3      0     4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`groupby.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

            False  True 
Filter 1      4      0
Filter 2      2      2
Filter 3      0      4
```